# Error in conversion from const uint8_t* to uint8_t*

Tags: c++, casting, arduino, arduino-ide

Trying to build a code for Arduino Nano using this code. I have an error in conversion from `const uint8_t*` to `uint8_t*`. Absolutely understand the problem but I don't know how to fix this.

```
  myOLED.drawBitmap(0, 0, VUMeter, 128, 64);       // draws background
```

VUMeter described as:

```
const uint8_t VUMeter[] PROGMEM = {...}
```

Function drawBitmap from the library OLED:

```
drawBitmap(int x, int y, uint8_t* bitmap, int sx, int sy);
```

Could you please help me to understand the way to fix the problem?

Comment: It's certainly a flaw in your library and drawBitmap does not modify the bitmap. A simple cast should help.

Comment: @datafiddler, but I guess it will not read the array from PROGMEM

Comment: because it would have to read it with functions which access the PROGMEM. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Comment: How can a function convert from `uint8_t*` to `uint8_t*`? There's no conversion at all to be done.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, read more closely

Comment: @datafiddler casting away constness with either a C-style cast or `const_cast` risks undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, theoretically. That's why the compiler wants you to confirm explicitly. Here it's to bypass an error in the library, which should rather be fixed.

Comment: @Juraj: you're right about PROGMEM; sorry.

Comment: @datafiddler it's not just theoretical.  Once you start doing casts the compiler might make other assumptions which simply aren't true.  My favorite article on the subject is [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: @MarkRansom, I'm not sure that time travelling is the best argument to prove "it's not just theoretical" ;-)  But joking aside, are there any practical examples of compilers that do not allow this cast for this specific scenario? Does the compiler know in any way that the specific memory region is not writable? Are you basically implying that it is by definition impossible to create a working application using this library due this stupid bug in the API?

Comment: A machine designed to detect **undefined behavior** and do funny things, because it is allowed to do so, is nice. But I'd prefer not to use it for myself.

Comment: @wovano the article is all about actual observed behavior from contemporary compilers, but nothing covering this specific scenario.  But once you've seen what's possible, it's not hard to imagine that this could go wrong in very unexpected ways.  That said I've used this particular casting workaround myself, but it's hard to recommend something where the next version of the compiler could break things spectacularly.

Comment: @datafiddler you may be using the wrong language then.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to fix and enhance your library. Change

`drawBitmap(int x, int y, uint8_t* bitmap, int sx, int sy);`

to

`drawBitmap(int x, int y,const uint8_t* bitmap, int sx, int sy);`

and add an additional method

`drawBitmap_P (int x, int y, const uint8_t* bitmap, int sx, int sy);`

which takes the bitmap bytes from PROGMEM